# Understanding ExtJS model associations

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am trying to understand how ExtJS associations work. I have not found an understandable tutorial on this issue that covers my main two use cases and especially how ExtJS differentiates between the two:

- Association between two models through an "Id" reference.
- Association between two models through a Parent-Child relationship.

[I have laid the ground in this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2afa), can someone help me to fill in the gaps?

Comment: I'm confused... are you just trying to populate the SubItems grid when you select an item in ComplexData?  What do you mean by differentiates between the two items you've listed?

Comment: @incutonez When I am syncing, ExtJS has to build the association on the newly created objects. It can do by either making the subitems a list of child objects, or by referencing the master record by Id from the child records.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **fields: [
        {name: 'AA', mapping: 'qq'},
        {name: 'SS', mapping: 'pp'},
    ]**

The **name** you write the name given in gui part 
eg:
{
xtype:'mytext',
label:'',
**name:'AA',**
editable:true
}

when you receive responses like this and in xml so the data is mapped like this:
*<wer>
<qq>data</qq>
<>data</>
</wer>*


so, we map the response data to name in gui.....
```